# Android - Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, eclipse-adt

In one of my project I am using Google-map. It is asking the API key, how can I get it? Can I complete the project without that key? All other things are working fine.
Thank you for any help...

Comment: Without Key your app is working fine but you're not able to load Map...

Comment: That means it is showing errors in logcat regarding the api key..

Comment: @AS yes.. off course ...it'll give a error...

Comment: Ya that only I'm asking how to get that key..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont have the api key of google maps your map not load.

You can see this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=pt-PT#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key) to create de key and insert it in your project.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create project in google console and enable the credentials there you can create the api key follow this link
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start?hl=pt-PT#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key